# Sharepoint framework .sppkg webpart on-premises app cataglog issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I am deploying hello-world app to an on premises app catalog. I am creating the app with SharePoint framework after building and running gulp package-solution. When i upload the .sppkg from SharePoint/solution , app catalog shows that "NO" in "Valid app package". So app not asks for the permissions and deployment

[image]

this is my SharePoint Configuration database version:
16.0.4483.1000

Answer (score 0):

As [SharePoint Framework roadmap](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/roadmap) mentioned, the on premise SPFx support will be shipping as part of Feature Pack for SharePoint 2016 version during calendar year 2017.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint framework is not yet released for on-Premises. It is getting failed to deploy.

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti